# DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ifihan rotimi-olu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\ifihan rotimi-olu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\ifihan rotimi-olu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\users\ifihan rotimi-olu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\users\ifihan rotimi-olu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: Please refer the similar issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474219/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initiali).