# Tensorflow - ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: tensorflow

I am struggling to utilise TensorFlow within Jupyter notebook. I have installed TensorFlow via Anaconda Prompt (running as admin). But when I go to call it in my notebook I get the following error string (sorry this is long).

Any help or thoughts would be welcomed here - should I run a full uninstall and try again?

kind regards
Jack

I am running:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

The error message is as follows (there are a number of others but this is the first and the rest have similar issue):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jjcon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\jjcon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\jjcon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\jjcon\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\jjcon\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are facing any other issues possible reasons are

- Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) and [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).