# ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed; TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an ai that detects object with the help of this(https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model) link and I ran into a problem when I finished the installation and was checking for errors using the code

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

#### My system:

> Windows 10
>
> Python 3.7.0
>
> TensorFlow 2.4.0

#### Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: Why this is tagged django?

Comment: TensorFlow release binaries are prebuilt with AVX instruction sets. Therefore on any CPU that does not have these instruction sets, either CPU or GPU version of TF will fail to load. For other possible reason you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62071101/14290681), thanks!