# Python: How do I resolve this ImportError?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, python-import

I installed Tensorflow through `pip install` and it was successful but when i try to use it I have this ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AKIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AKIN/PythonProjects/sample_codes/trial_tf.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\AKIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\AKIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\AKIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AKIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I have checked this and I have seen Windows build failing but I don't know if that's what affecting it:

> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

What is going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60474219/2650249

Comment: Simply install Anaconda on your computer (Look up online, it's available as a `.exe`) and simply run this command: `conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu `. Then try using Tensorflow Again

Answer (score 1):

After hundreds of Google searches and Youtube videos, I found the solution to this problem about a month ago. Unlike other third-party modules in python (e.g. Pandas, Matplotlib, etc.)- which require `pip` install - there are a different set of steps including installing NVIDIA with a Cuda-enabled GPU or CPU (Tensorflow works with either one) and activating a cond environment.

One youtube video I found to be particularly useful briefly explains each step to installing tensorflow without a `DLL` error. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ym-dOS9ssA&t=327s

The instructor uses Pycharm, but I am sure you can easily follow each step with another IDE.

If you have any questions or want clarification, please do not hesitate to ask. Best of luck! :)